# Approaching foreign languages and SEO-friendly URLs query

Tags: url, seo

I'm a beginner regarding SEO, so I'm basically trying to create SEO friendly URLs via mod-rewrite for example:

www.website.com?title=The-Big-Book
to
www.website.com/The-Big-Book

The question I have at the moment is how should I approach this if there is a chance the title (user defined) will be in a foreign language such as Chinese?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^/?([^/.]+)$ **YOUR REWRITE RULES**`

Answer (score 0):

i would say just pick a good format for your url, (your example is not a good example of a good format), browsers support foreign languages so you dont have to worry about that.

Comment: you can try translating the title and puting it in the html code (hided from everyone but google, so that page will be ranked in both languages. im not so sure about this but i think it can work.